# Map two or more properties to one property in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map two strings to one string in automapper.

I think it has something to do with using [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html), but I can't get my head around it.

This is wrong but something like this:

```
CreateMap<TestClass, SecondClass.ThirdClass>.ForMember(x => x.Test, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.FirstString && z => z.SecondString)) 


public class TestClass {    
        public string FirstString { get; set; }
        public string SecondString { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass {
    public class ThirdClass {
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like Test to contain FirstString + SecondString.

Comment: Can just use simple interpolation - `y => y.MapFrom(z => $"{z.FirstString} {z.SecondString)}")`

Comment: You're welcome, I've added it as an answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use string interpolation - `y => y.MapFrom(z => $"{z.FirstString} {z.SecondString)}")`